# hooking up a belkin USB switch

Tags: usb, printing

I'm trying to help my parents hook up a Belkin 4-Port USB switch (model F1U200V) to a couple of USB printers, however, Google hasn't been able to find a manual. a picture can befound at [http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-F1U200V-4-Port-USB-Switch/dp/B000EJUCVE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EJUCVE) Could someone point me in the right direction please? Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: If you need to connect more than one device (printer), you'll need a USB Hub, plug the hub into the single downstream port on the Switch and the printers into the hub. The four upstream ports go to 4 different computers ("host" in USB parlance).

Answer (score 1):

Hook up the 'printer' port to the printer. Hook up the other four ports to up to four computers. Push the soft-touch switch until the light next to the port you want to print from lights up. Then install the printer drivers (if you haven't already) on the selected computer and print.

It sounds like you don't want a switch though. You have multiple *printers*. You need a USB hub, not a switch. USB switches connect multiple hosts to the same device. You want to hook multiple devices to the same host.